# How to iterate over two lists of subnets on a single stateful firewall rule in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to develop a firewall rule that will scale easily and only require the update of the var.source subnets list rather than hardcode the IPs into the firewall rule. When trying the example code, I get two errors:

1. Error: Insufficient Header Blocks; At least 1 "header" block are required"
2. In the dynamic header block, I get an error "unsupported attribute" on the "for_each = var.source_subnets.value" line. It says "var.source_subnets is a list of string with 3 elements. This value does not have any attributes."

I have made sure the syntax is correct in my .tfvars and variables.tf files when referencing the variables. I have also tried changing the source in the dynamic header block to

```
source = var.source_subnets
```

and

```
source = header.value
```

and

```
source = header.key
```

Here is the entire block of code I have tried last:

```
dynamic "stateful_rule" {
  for_each = var.refinitiv_ips
  iterator = "refinitiv_ips_rule"
  
  content {
    action = "PASS"

    dynamic "header" {
      for_each = var.source_subnets

      content {
        destination = refinitiv_ips_rule.value
        destination_port = 3342
        direction = "ANY"
        protocol = "TCP"
        source = header.value
        source_port = "ANY"
      }
    }

    rule_option {
      keyword = "sid:${refinitiv_ips_rule.key + 10}"
    }
  }
}
```

What I am expecting is to have each subnet in var.refinitiv_ips and var.source_subnets be iterated over to pass in a single 5-tuple firewall.

Comment: You forgot to provide actual value of `var.source_subnets`.

Comment: My value is set in my .tfvars file

Comment: OK. So what exactly is it?

Answer (score 0):

if the subnets variable contents is a set of strings, then instead of using header.value, header.key should be used.

```
dynamic "header" {
  for_each = var.source_subnets

  content {
    destination = refinitiv_ips_rule.value
    destination_port = 3342
    direction = "ANY"
    protocol = "TCP"
    source = header.value
    source_port = "ANY"
  }
}
```

reference: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each